# Collision stops enemies from attacking - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, collision

I have a simple game where a player defends a central base from attacking enemies. Currently when the player touches the base the enemies all stop attacking. Attacks are handled by a co-routine in the Enemy script. I have posted the enemy and base scripts below.
ENEMY SCRIPT

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {

public static float Damage = 10.0f;
public float Health = 20.0f;

public Transform target;
public float Speed;

public bool isAttacking = false;

//If the player collides with the enemy
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("Player hits enemy");
        Health -= PlayerController.Damage;
        Debug.Log("Enemy health at: " + Health);
    }
}


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //Destroy the enemy if it's health reaches 0
        if(Health <= 0){
            isAttacking = false;
            Debug.Log ("Is attacking: " + isAttacking);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            Debug.Log ("Enemy Destroyed!");
        }

    //Constantly move the enemy towards the centre of the gamespace (where the base is)
    float step = Speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
}
}
```

BASE SCRIPT

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Base : MonoBehaviour {

public float Health = 100f;
public float AttackSpeed = 2f;

//VOID AWAKE - START . contains getcomponent code
public Enemy enemy;
void awake(){
    enemy = GetComponent<Enemy>();
}
//VOID AWAKE - END

//If enemy touches the base 
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
    Debug.Log ("Base touched");
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" && Health > 0f){
        enemy.isAttacking = true;
        Debug.Log ("Enemy attacking base");
        StartCoroutine("enemyAttack");
    }
    else{
        enemy.isAttacking = false;
    }
}

//Coroutine that deals damage
public IEnumerator enemyAttack(){
    while(Health > 0f){
        if(enemy.isAttacking == true){
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            Health -= Enemy.Damage;
            Debug.Log ("Base health at: " + Health);
        }else{
            yield break;
        }
    }
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //Load Lose Screen when Base health reaches 0
    if (Health <= 0){
        Application.LoadLevel("Lose Screen");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: so what's your question.. also I will ask did you set breakpoints in the current code that you have posted and step through ..?

Comment: It's a little hard to word but basically, when the player touches the base it stops the enemies from attacking. I don't want this to happen. I am adding breakpoints now and stepping through the code a little slower but just wanted some pointers if it was something obvious

Comment: Nobody has the time to wade through a huge code dump. You need to narrow down the problem yourself first using the normal debugging process. Do that *first* and then post if you still are having trouble.

Comment: most people will not respond to question that deal with Gaming since not all programmers do game development perhaps SO needs to start a separate room for this type of stuff

Comment: @MethodMan Thought they did: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I wouldn't know @TyCobb since I don't do game development but that's a `Good to know` thanks

Comment: I personally like looking at other people's game logic, provided there's enough information to discern what the problem actually is. But I may just represent a small minority of those on SO. =P

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is with the logic here:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
    Debug.Log ("Base touched");
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" && Health > 0f){
        enemy.isAttacking = true;
        Debug.Log ("Enemy attacking base");
        StartCoroutine("enemyAttack");
    }
    else{
        enemy.isAttacking = false;
    }
}
```

NoW your condition is:

```
if(col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" && Health > 0f)
```

So if the thing colliding with the base (if I'm understanding this correctly) is not "Enemy", then you go into the else clause:

```
enemy.isAttacking = false;
```

And stop the enemy attacking.

Probably what you want is something like:

```
if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
{
    if (Health > 0f) 
    {
        //...do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        enemy.isAttacking = false;
    }
}
```

Now something that isn't the enemy touching your base won't stop affect the enemy.

But it's hard to tell when you dump code in a question with little or no explanation, so this could be way off.